# read complex financial tables using R or Python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, nlp, finance

I have about 100 reports like below where there is a table with financial information I need to extract. The job is too big to do manually.

I need to extract the 'key persons' name and total renumeration, and save this in some sort of table.
The **challenge** which I'm sure many of you are aware of is that extracting data from PDFs in in Python or R or extremely difficult. What makes it harder is that each company presents a slightly different table compared to the one below.

What I need is some systematic method of grabbing the required information. I am not asking by any means for a solution, as I know it is a big task, instead I am looking for advice in how to achieve my goal.
I have used all the regular Python and R packages, and so far I have not come up with any great systematic way of completing my task. Possibly a machine learning approach is the way to go? I'm not sure. But I have tried many methods of completing this task, to no avail.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

[image: table]

Comment: text in PDF's is placed at absolute coordinates on the page. So no logical ordering in the file is needed to get some text in the table at row X and column Y, you have to render the page to determine X and Y

Comment: probably best to tell us more specifically what you've tried. Of course, the first approach we're going to recommend is that you use e.g., `library(pdftools)` and `stringr` and a bunch of regex and logical to find the bits you want, and if your pdfs are images then you're going to want to use `library(tesseract)` (which uses OCR to grab text from images), but if you've already tried that and found that approach is going to have to be totally bespoke for each pdf then there's no point developing a solution down those lines.

Comment: https://blog.djnavarro.net/posts/2023-06-16_tabulizer/

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.djnavarro.net/posts/2023-06-16_tabulizer/

There's a nice blog post from Danielle Navarro. For prosperity (in case that link disappears): use the `library(tabulizer)` . It depends on java, and you'll need to `install.packages("rJava")` and bottom-out whatever reasons that's not installing (i.e., you haven't got openjdk, or whatever (that's going to be os dependent)), and then maybe with a bit of luck you can use `tabulizer::extract_tables(file = "your.pdf")` and grab the tables you want.

Without a more reprex it's not really possible to help you more - post a link to the pdf you're wanting to extract tables from, and perhaps I can do some more.